# Copy and Paste creates random null objects from existing geometry

Tags: objects, edit-mode, shortcut, error, object-mode

i have a really annoying and strange copy & paste bug.

Sometimes when i want to copy & paste an object, blender creates random null objects from my existing geometry, sometimes everything is deleted exept the copied object.
I couldn't reproduce this bug in a new file.

Maybe changed some settings accidentally with a shortcut?

Iam using Blender 2.9 A

Best, Joseph

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your project looks very elaborate and professional. Like the kind of thing you wouldn't want to lose to a system crash. So I'm wondering why you're using an Alpha, instead of, say, anything else.

Comment: @R-800 Thank You! I think because of the optiX viewport denoising :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to duplicate objects in your scene, instead of using Ctrl-C to copy them, consider using Shift-D instead. Admitedly. It's a bit confusing that there are both methods available when they don't seem to completely work the same way. I don't use Ctrl-C for anything except copying poses in Pose Mode. And I have no issues. Interestingly, when I just tried to use Ctrl-C on an object in a scene, as you have done, I got a weird result also: It made an extra copy of my armature object. However, it's an armature that wasn't even part of the object I tried to copy. Very odd.

Comment: Ahhhh i see! Never used Ctrl-D to be honest... try to get used to it! Thank You!

Comment: That was Shift-D. I don't think there even *is* a Ctrl-D shortcut... shockingly enough!  :)

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this very problem for years, I have just figured out the solution.

Whenever you copy an object from one file to another, Blender copies everything that that object relies on or have dependencies on, this means every other object referred to in modifiers, materials, physics, constraint, etc., assigned to the selected object.

For my problem, it was an empty referred to in the material I was using for the copied and pasted objects: Blender was pasting a lot of empties that were assigned to "object" field of *Coordinate Texture* nodes in the materials, and every time you paste an object, even if it brings the very same material, Blender will create a new instance of that material, and also paste a new empty if there's one assigned to anything inside the material.

The solution was easy: I just removed the materials from the object, and there it is, never again getting those annoying empties.

Most likely, the problem is in modifiers, physics, parenting, or materials assigned to these objects you're copying. Look for references to empties anywhere, and remove/apply them, and the empties will no longer be pasted together with your objects.